# Awesome Player Error - 3G Only

Tags: android

I have some code that plays an `MP3 stream`, and when running on `wifi` this is working flawlessly.  When I try to run exactly the same code on a 3G connection, `AwesomePlayer` returns a `-1004 error`, with no `HTTP` errors.

There is a copy of the log below.

I have tried connecting to the server using the internet browser and this works fine, so it's not a routing issue.

```
08-02 11:31:41.018: VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(1238): Client(14) constructor
08-02 11:31:41.018: VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(1238): Create new client(14) from pid 4482, url=http://212.48.126.146:8060, connId=14, audioSessionId=16
08-02 11:31:41.018: VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(1238): setDataSource(http://212.48.126.146:8060)
08-02 11:31:41.018: VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(1238): getPlayerTypeFromMAP(http://212.48.126.146:8060): PLAYERS_MAP[25].playertype 0
08-02 11:31:41.018: VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(1238): player type = 4
08-02 11:31:41.018: VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(1238):  create StagefrightPlayer
08-02 11:31:41.018: VERBOSE/AudioSink(1238): AudioOutput(16)
08-02 11:31:41.018: VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(1238):  setDataSource
08-02 11:31:41.018: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(1238): setDataSource('http://212.48.126.146:8060')
08-02 11:31:41.018: VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(1238): [14] setAudioStreamType(3)
08-02 11:31:41.018: VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(1238): [14] prepareAsync
08-02 11:31:41.018: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(1238): overrides append
08-02 11:31:41.018: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(1238): connect to 212.48.126.146:8060/ @0
08-02 11:31:41.018: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(1238): ENTER connect
08-02 11:31:41.018: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(1238): [Stagefright] 212.48.126.146 is not localhost
08-02 11:31:41.018: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(1238): [Stagefright] do not use http proxy 
08-02 11:31:41.018: INFO/HTTPStream(1238): start connect_nonb
08-02 11:31:41.108: INFO/HTTPStream(1238): back from connect_nonb
08-02 11:31:41.108: INFO/HTTPStream(1238): start connect_nonb
08-02 11:31:41.228: INFO/HTTPStream(1238): back from connect_nonb
08-02 11:31:41.398: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(1238): LEAVE connect
08-02 11:31:41.398: INFO/AwesomePlayer(1238): mConnectingDataSource->connect() returned -1004
08-02 11:31:41.398: VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(1238): [14] notify (0x38350, 100, 1, -1004)
08-02 11:31:41.408: ERROR/MediaPlayer(4482): error (1, -1004)
08-02 11:31:41.408: ERROR/MediaPlayer(4482): Error (1,-1004)
```

If anyone has any ideas I can try I would be grateful.

Many thanks in advance,

Neil.

Answer (score 0):

it may be your 3g connection error. check your 3g connection.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, but I have double checked and my 3G connection is fine, I can use the internet with no problem and as I stated in my original post I can connect to the server providing the stream with a web browser and it's fine.

Comment: where you are getting the media via local LAN or Internet. Where is that audio link local or in web?

Comment: The stream is coming from the internet.  I have since discovered that this is specific to O2, and the problem doesn't occur if I use my 3 sim in the phone.  So clearly it's a provider block of somekind, but it would be nice to find a way around it.  I'm also having problems with the MediaPlayer on a different stream where it takes a really long time (up to 15 minutes) to start playing the stream whether on Wifi or 3g.  I confess I'm finding the platform somewhat frustrating after developing similar software for the iPhone and it just plays the stream when you tell it to.